# Correctly splitting a CSV file after repetition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

I have CSV containing 5000 rows, every few hundred CSV lines there is a repeating section.
What is the most efficient option to divide this file into several different ones?

**File looks like**

```
Header1
number of Samples1
Content1
a1, aa1, aaa1
b1, bb1, bbb1
....
Header2
number of Samples2
Content2
a2, aa2, aaa2
b2, bb2, bbb2
....
Header3
number of Samples3
Content3
a3, aa3, aaa3
b3, bb3, bbb3
```

I need to split it into a few files by `Header`. And I have no idea how can I do that. I write the whole script to process some biological stuff, but one of the files types (above) generates problems because it is several files in one. And the script does not want to work with it.

I've read a lot about the splitting files, but I've found nothing about the separation after repeating values in pandas.

In this case, it would be 3 files (but the number of these files in files varies)

Comment: Is the content size constant? If yes, you can have a count variable to track when the new section begins. If no, you can read content lines in endless loop and have a `break` condition on non-content line (which will be the new header).

Comment: No, size isn't constant. But breaking statement it's good advice, thank U! I will try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bit better solution than `break` statements, as I suggested in comment:

You can create the `result` list and store each chunk data in separate element of list (in dict, for example). If you read non-**Header** line, you can guarantee, that the line you just read is related to the current chunk of data. And the current chunk of data is the last element in `result` list, so you can just modify it. If you read the **Header** line, you just append the new element to the `result` and start to write new chunk data into it.

If the size of content is constant, you can use the `itertools.cycle` iterator that will "codify" your parsing process:

```
from itertools import cycle

text1 = """Header1
number of Samples1
Content1
a1, aa1, aaa1
b1, bb1, bbb1
Header2
number of Samples2
Content2
a2, aa2, aaa2
b2, bb2, bbb2"""
size = 5
iterator = cycle(range(size))
result = []
for line in text1.split('\n'):
    i = next(iterator)
    if i == 0:
        result.append({'header': line})
    elif i == 1:
        result[-1]['num_of_samples'] = line
    elif i == 2:
        result[-1]['content_header'] = line
    elif i == 3:
        result[-1]['content'] = [line.split(', ')]
    else:
        result[-1]['content'].append(line.split(', '))
```

If you don't know the size of content, you should parse each line, check its type and construct your data manually:

```
text2 = """Header1
number of Samples1
Content1
a1, aa1, aaa1
b1, bb1, bbb1
b1, bb1, bbb1
Header2
number of Samples2
Content2
b2, bb2, bbb2
Header3
number of Samples3
Content3
a3, aa3, aaa3
b3, bb3, bbb3"""
result = []
i = 0
for line in text2.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('Header'):  # Your condition for headers
        result.append({'header': line})
    elif line.startswith('number'):  # Your condition for number of samples
        result[-1]['num_of_samples'] = line
    elif line.startswith('Content'):  # Your condition for content headers
        result[-1]['content_header'] = line
    else:
        if 'content' not in result[-1]:  # We don't know is the content list created
            result[-1]['content'] = [line.split(', ')]
        else:
            result[-1]['content'].append(line.split(', '))
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great. Thank u so much!